# How to produce image "magnification" effect on iOS?

Tags: objective-c, ios

Is swapping 2 images a standard solution? Is there a better way?

Specifically imagine an image on screen, which (upon tap) should increases in size 30%.

Please provide an example.

Comment: There is a magnifying glass control I've had great experiences with here: http://cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/ios-magnifyingglass

Comment: I don't quite get what you exactly want. Do you mean the magnifying of a textfield or you just want to scale an image?

Comment: @yinkou, Scaling an image. Sorry for not being clear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

apply a basic view animation to your imageview.

```
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                 animations:^{
                     yourImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.3, 1.3);
                 }
    ];
```

Comment: Would not this distort the original image?

Comment: No, just the view.
You can "reset" it by applying the identity transform.